# Как получить все атрибуты из html элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как получить все атрибуты тега `a` в виде массива?

```
<a data-key1="5" data-key2="7"></a>
```

Comment: атрибуты могут быть **только** `data-*`? или другие тоже нужны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

За получение `data-*` атрибутов отвечает метод [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

**Чтобы получить все `data-*` атрибуты:**

```js
/* Получаем все свойства */
var data = $('#test').data();

/* Для демонстрации */
$('body').append($('<ul>').attr('id', 'result'));

/* Выводим свойства */
for (var key in data) {
  $('<li>', {
    text: key + ': ' + data[key]
  }).appendTo('#result');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" data-key1="5" data-key2="7"></a>
```

**Чтобы получить все свойства:**

```js
/* Получаем все свойства */
var attributes = document.getElementById('test').attributes;

/* Для демонстрации */
$('body').append($('<ul>').attr('id', 'result'));

/* Перебираем свойства */
for (var key in attributes) {
  /* Выбираем именно html-атрибуты */
  if (attributes[key].nodeName) {
    $('<li>', {
      text: attributes[key].nodeName + ': ' + attributes[key].nodeValue
    }).appendTo('#result');
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="test" data-key1="5" data-key2="7"></a>
```

Основано на ответах:

- [Get all Attributes from a HTML element with Javascript/jQuery](http://Get%20all%20Attributes%20from%20a%20HTML%20element%20with%20Javascript/jQuery)
- [Get list of data-* attributes using javascript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187032/get-list-of-data-attributes-using-javascript-jquery)

Comment: заметь, что `id` не вывелось.

Comment: судя по примеру я предположил, что автору нужно вывести `data-*` атрибуты

Comment: у него просто написано _все_, я поэтому у него уточнил в комментарии

Comment: Да, спасибо! Отличное решение для пользовательских атрибутов. Пытался получить через `.attr()`, но не вышло.

Comment: @Mike, потому что `attr` - выдает _конкретный_ атрибут. Так же можешь посмотреть [свойство attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) у элемента - в нем хранятся **все** атрибуты.

Comment: @Mike я дополнил ответ